# how to call a windows phone 8 code-behind method from html input button click

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-8

i want to call a c# method from html page in windows phone 8. currently i am trying with the following code but it is not working

**JavaScript:**

```
 <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="window.external.something();" />
```

**and my c# method in mainpage.xaml**

```
void something()
{
MessageBox.Show("called from javascript");
}
```

can any one tell me the way to call a c# code behind method from java-script. i.e how to pass variables from javascript to c# method and vice-versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `window.external.notify("string")` and have to register to the `ScriptNotify` event of the browser in the code behind in order to receive the call.

You register this way:

```
MyWebBrowser.ScriptNotify+=OnScriptNotify;
```

You consume this way:

```
OnScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e){
    //do something e.Value contains the string passed as a parameter
}
```

To do the inverse (calling a function in JavaScript from code behind) you do:

```
MyWebBrowser.InvokeScript("functionName");
MyWebBrowser.InvokeScript("functionWithParam", "param1", "param2");
```

Those function return an object.

Be sure to make your web browser work with JavaScript by setting `MyWebBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;`

Comment: how to register the notify events from code behind. can you please post the detailed explanation. because it is showing me error at  this line window.external.notify("string")

Comment: we cannot call a method to a paticular click event

Comment: I'm not very fond of javascript the command is right, I don't know if you can call it directly from onclick maybe you have to pass it a function instead, anyway be sure that WebBrowser isScriptEnabled is true and that you set the right capabilities in the manifest

Comment: I can verify that this technique works. From Javascript you call "window.external.notify('commandText'); and in the OnScriptNotify in C# the e.Value will hold the string you pass in (ie 'commandText')